# Что такое production-сервер?

Tags: php

Что такое **production-сервер**? (в веб-программировании)

Comment: Зачем кто-то пытается закрыть вопрос как опросник? Это же не опросник, а нормальный вопрос...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Production-окружение** - это рабочее, так называемое "боевое" окружение, в котором производится работа с реальными клиентам и актуальными данными. Production-сервер - это сервер, относящийся к production-окружению. На production-сервере должна находиться стабильная, оттестированная сборка.

Говоря о веб-программировании, http://stackoverflow.com - это "боевой", продакшновый сайт StackOverflow.

Этому термину обычно противопоставляются понятия **тестовое** окружение и тестовый сервер - он не доступен сторонним пользователям и используется разработчиками для разработки, отладки и тестирования новых версий продукта. Зачастую, тестовый сервер работает либо с тестовыми, не реальными данными (если данные являются конфиденциальными. например, в банковской сфере), либо с копией данных (во избежание ошибочных изменений).

Answer (score 2):

Это сервер, на котором крутится запущено живое приложение с настоящими данными, доступ к которому имеют настоящие пользователи. В отличие от Staging - тестового окружения (пусть даже и работающего на копии данных), которое применяется прежде всего в целях тестирования перед релизом новой версии.